# Wrong arguments '"Male"': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException | Drools KieSession in HiveUDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, drools, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to develop a UDF with drools rule engine invocation inside evaluate method using the code below:

```
Person person = new Person(gender);

    KieServiceSerializer kszObj = new KieServiceSerializer();

    KieServices ks = kszObj.getKieServices();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");   //this line is causing error: Wrong arguments '"Male"': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.udf_drools_poc.UDFDrools.evaluate(java.lang.String)

    kSession.insert(person);
    kSession.fireAllRules();
```

Both Person and KieServiceSerializer are serialized.

This code works fine locally (when executed from IDE) but throws following error when executed through hive:

```
Wrong arguments '"Male"': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.udf_drools_poc.UDFDrools.evaluate(java.lang.String)
```

Invoking UDF using the script below:

```
create temporary function genderMap as 'org.udf_drools_poc.UDFDrools';
select genderMap("Male");
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What hive UDF are you using? Edit the question and add details about the UDF and where are you using `Male object or variable`.

Comment: It's a hiveUDF and added the udf invocation details.

Comment: How and where are you inserting the object?

Comment: I've added the insert object line of code but while debugging I've checked - it's throwing an error while creating the KieSession.

Comment: Can you add a sample reproducer? One more thing this error might be because your query to the hive is wrong. Your UDF should accept a column name, not a String value. The hive query should be `select genderMap(column_name)`.

Comment: I'm quite sure it works even if you pass a string value and doesn't require a column name (I've tested and it worked with string value multiple times). I'm sorry, what do you mean by sample reproducer?

Comment: A sample project with sample code is the reproducer

Comment: yes this has got nothing to do with column value, it can very well be a string, passing a string constant to UDF is perfectly acceptable.